# why my basic date picker couldn't convert the input into the datetime format ?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm using basic date picker for vb.net and oracle as my database. when i insert the date from basic date picker, i got this error >> ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL

this is my code :

```
    Private Function GetDate(ByVal bdp1 As Date) As DataSet

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source = ***; User ID =***; Password =**;"
    Dim sqlConnection As OracleClient.OracleConnection = New OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectionString)

    Dim queryString As String = "select * from smsdw.lot_act where tran_dttm <= ('" & bdp1 & "' , 'MM/DD/YYYY') and tran_dttm > ('" & bdp1 & "', 'MM/DD/YYYY')"

    Dim sqlCommand As OracleClient.OracleCommand = New OracleClient.OracleCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0

    Dim dataAdapter As OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter = New OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)

    Return dataSet

End Function
```

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, instead:

```
Dim queryString As String = "select * from smsdw.lot_act where tran_dttm <= :dtm1 and tran_dttm > :dtm2"

Dim sqlCommand As OracleClient.OracleCommand = New OracleClient.OracleCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("dtm1",bdp1)
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("dtm2",bdp1)
```

Which a) avoids the possibility of SQL injection, and b) Keeps the date *as* a date throughout, rather than mangling it to/from a string.

It doesn't fix the logical issue with your query though - where you're trying to find a row where `tran_dttm` is both "less than or equal" **and** "greater than" the **same** value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
Dim queryString As String = "select * from smsdw.lot_act where tran_dttm <= cdate('" & bdp1.Value.ToString & "') and tran_dttm > cdate('" & bdp1.Value.ToString  & "')"
```

Comment: tq but i got this error >> ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim queryString As String = "select * from smsdw.lot_act where tran_dttm <= '" & bdp1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "' and tran_dttm > '" & bdp1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "'"
```

But for oracle the default datetime format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. You have three options:

- Change the default file format for the one that suits your desires
- Use the default format: `bdp1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`
- Use the `todate` oracle function specifiying the read format:
  `" to_date('" & bdp1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "', 'mm/dd/yyyy') "`

Comment: tq but doesnt work i got this error >> ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: This is because the oracle datetime format, which by default is `YYYY-MM-DD`. I edit my answer to give you the solution

Comment: yeah but now i got error >> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis